# Getting unique word frequencies

Tags: python

I'm working on the following code to get the 10 least common words in a group of files:

```
import os

data_directory = "/pubmed/"

file_list = os.listdir(data_directory)

string_freq = {}

for file in file_list:
    f = open(data_directory + file, 'r')
    ftext = f.read()
    new_text = ftext.replace("\n", "")
    string_list = new_text.split(" ")
    for word in string_list:
        if word in string_freq:
            string_freq[word] += 1
        else:
            string_freq[word]  = 1
f.close()

for word in sorted (string_frequency, key = string_frequency.get, reverse=False)[:10]:
    print(word, string_freq[word])
```

Now, here's the thing: I am getting a list of 10 words, but they all have the same frequency count of 1. The results look like this:

```
Evaluation 1
reviews 1
decision 1
ankle 1
knee 1
postreduction 1
shoulder 1
nursemaid's 1
elbows 1
Thermal 1
```

How can I skip over words that have the same frequency, so that the results will look like: Evaluation 1, otherword 2, thirdword 3, fourthword 4, etc.? I really don't want to use any other libraries besides the standard libraries of `os`, `string`, or `random`.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is a thing

Comment: You could make another dictionary from the first with the keys being frequency and the values being lists of words with that frequency. Then you just choose a word from each of the lists.

Comment: Can you upload a zip of the source data you're testing against?

Comment: If thereare more than one word with a frequency, how do you choose the one you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, for example:

```
string_frequency = {'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'three': 1, 'four': 2, 'five': 2, 'six': 3, 'seven': 3, 'eight': 3}

words = sorted(string_frequency, key=string_frequency.get, reverse=False)
word_frequencies = {string_frequency[word]: word for word in words}

for frequency in sorted(word_frequencies):
    print(frequency, word_frequencies[frequency])
```

**Output**

```
1 three
2 four
3 seven
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the key-value association and then sort the resulting dict. This will override duplicate frequencies:

```
>>> sorted({v: k for k, v in string_freq.items()}.items())
```